Value Error : Sequential model 'sequential_3' has no defined input shape yet
What are common mistakes or omissions that cause the '`Sequential model has no defined input shape1 error?
Do preprocessing layers (like resize_and_rescale or data_augmentation) impact the input_shape in the first layer of the model?
What is the purpose of the input_shape parameter in the first layer of a Keras Sequential model?
input_shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)
n_classes = 3

model = models.Sequential([
    resize_and_rescale,
    data_augmentation,
    layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape = input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'),
])

the error says
Value Error : Sequential model 'sequential_3' has no defined input shape yet


Try to add keras.Input(shape = input_shape) layer as the very first layer in your model

The preprocessing layers do not directly affect the input shape, the input
shape typically defines the expected dimensions of the input that the model
will process. As observed in your code, the layers for resizing and data
augmentation have not been defined. Please add those layers and explicitly
define the input layer, specifying the input shape.
